# What is a monotonic family of surfaces?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am following a paper by Eberhard Hopf titled *On S. Bernstein's Theorem on Surfaces z(x, y) of Nonpositive Curvature*. Not long into the proof for his first lemma, he makes a construction of spheres that satisfy certain properties. Then, he mentions that these spheres are a ***monotonic family of surfaces***.

I think I know what a family of surfaces is (ie, a set of surfaces). But what does he mean by ***monotonic***? My guess would be that they do not intersect. But given the construction they always intersect in a circle. So perhaps my second guess would be that they only intersect on a plane.

**EDIT**: To be more specific; the spheres taken into account all intersect in a circle on the $z=0$ plane. Then he takes the part of the sphere which is above this plane and this collection of surfaces is the one that he calls a monotonic family of surfaces. So he's referring to surfaces which intersect at the border and nothing else.

**EDIT 2** (probably should have done this sooner haha!): Here is the specific construction:

Suppose $z(x,y)$ is a function of class $C^2$ on a bounded open set $R\subset \mathbb{R^2}$. Now suppose that $z$ is also continuous on the border of $R$, which we call $B$. Now take $C$ to be a circle whose interior contains $R \cup B$.

Now we take the set $X = \{\text{spheres which intersect the }\: z=0\: \text{plane on }\: C\}$. From this set we construct now:
$$
X^{+} = \{ \text{parts of the spheres from }X\: \text{that have}\: z\geq 0  \}
$$
It is $X^{+}$ what he calls the monotonic family of surfaces.

Comment: Maybe he's talking about a filtration?

Comment: What is a filtration? Pardon my ignorance

Comment: A filtration is a sequence of inclusions.  This is probably not the case here, I spoke too soon!  Can you give any more details?

Comment: @ZxJx sure! I can maybe give the full construction in the question. It is not long.

Comment: Ok, I think "monotonicity" refers to the distance between points in each surface.

Comment: I was wrong again!  I was looking at Osserman's proof of Berstein's theorem, which I think he does differently.  The monotonicity in your case is a ratio of areas, as in (https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/11df/e420b35ba20c9fcfd27fd3f128157df63865.pdf), page 31, Theorem 2.6.2.  I think one distiction to be made is that in the OP, there is no fixed center of these spheres.  If you fix a center, then "monotonic" is referring to the monotonicity of a real function (the function takes the radius of a sphere to the ratio of areas)

Comment: In general "monotonic" refers to a function that preserves some partial order.  So a "monotonic family of surfaces", one must specify two sets (in our case we want one set to be the parameter space with its endowed ordering) with respective partial orders, and a function between them.  I think in this case, the spheres are parametrized by their radii, so we have a partial ordering on the spheres.  In other situations, say if the parameter space has higher dimension, one would need to find a different partial order (often inclusion of sets) in order to speak of monotonicity.

Comment: Intuitively, if you take a ball and intersect it with your given surface, you can obtain a ratio of the area of the surface within the ball and the area of a disk inside the ball.  The larger the ball, the larger this ratio will be.  I think of this as giving the surface "more wiggle room", or from a different view: if your ball gets smaller, there is less "wiggle room" for the surface.

Comment: If you parametrize the spheres by the $z$-value of their centers, then there is a unique spherical slice in $X^+$ for each real number $z$. And indeed, every point in the upper half-space lies on exactly one of these slices. That is my guess for the interpretation.

Comment: This is all too helpful. Thanks to both of you!